# Can I get application changelogs using the terminal?

Tags: command-line, synaptic

In order to look at changelogs for recently updated applications, I use Synaptic. Is there a way for me to get specific application changelogs using the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aptitude changelog package`

Under natty and newer you should also be able to do:

`apt-get changelog package`

Comment: Excellent, just what I was looking for! Thank you :)

Comment: Once I've input the command to look at a change log, how would I go about quitting that command to input another?

Comment: Press the 'q' key.